# how to find class of a span used in <tr> of a kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid with large no of rows.In some of the rows few keywords are highlighted, ex:

row:  shubham, gupta, is a **student**

the word student has been highlighted by adding a css class(highlight) to it.
On inspection from chrome it looks like this :

```
<tr data-uid="35495e0b-7e1b-45e3-8058-562c97d2b24d" role="row">
  <td role="gridcell">shubham</td>
  <td role="gridcell">gupta</td>
  <td role="gridcell">
    <div style="word-wrap:break-word;height:50px;white-space: normal;overflow: auto;">
      is a <span class="highlight">student</span> = 32</div></td></tr>
```

i want to find the class of the span by jquery. I tried using :

```
$("#grid").find("tbody > tr>span>hasClass('highlight')");
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea, how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasClass` is method and not `selector`.

You can use below:

```
$("#grid").find("span.highlight")
```

to find all the `span` having class `highlight`.

**OR**

```
$("#grid span.highlight")
```

Comment: if the grid contains more than 1 span that has this higlight?

Comment: @shubhamgupta It'll return all the matched elements